# How do I ignore non numeric values for joined field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

```
SELECT * from table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 as t3 ON 
         CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', t3.reference_number, 3) > 3 
              THEN SUBSTRING(t3.reference_number, 3, CHARINDEX(':', t3.reference_number, 3) -3 ) 
              ELSE RIGHT(t3.reference_number, LEN(t3.reference_number) -2) end = Cast(t2.PurchaseOrderID as int)
```

I have a query like this above where I want to join on a table where the value I want to join on is a substring of the field itself. Something that field contains non-numeric values as well but I don't want to do the inner join on that field if that's the case.

How can I do that?

*t3.reference_number is the field that is in the format of O:###### when I want to inner join but can be any text any other time. I know this is terrible database design but it's a legacy system/db that I can't change right now.

---

For example:

t3.reference_number = "O:345215" where 345215 is the foreign key to another table that I want to join on

but if t3.reference_number = "hello" then I don't want to join because it will have a sql error due to not being able to convert the substring to an int because it's not numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... put your entire `CASE` in the `ISNUMERIC()` function and presto.

```
declare @table1 table (reference_number varchar(25))
declare @table2 table (PurchaseOrderID int)

insert into @table1 (reference_number)
select 'O:345215' union
select 'hello'

insert into @table2
select '345215'

select *
from @table1 t1
join @table2 t2
   on CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', t1.reference_number, 3) > 3 
              THEN SUBSTRING(t1.reference_number, 3, CHARINDEX(':', t1.reference_number, 3) -3 ) 
              ELSE RIGHT(t1.reference_number, LEN(t1.reference_number) -2) end = Cast(t2.PurchaseOrderID as int)
   and ISNUMERIC(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', t1.reference_number, 3) > 3 
              THEN SUBSTRING(t1.reference_number, 3, CHARINDEX(':', t1.reference_number, 3) -3 ) 
              ELSE RIGHT(t1.reference_number, LEN(t1.reference_number) -2) end) = 1
```